# Where can I upload the .p12 file or Push notification key on Parse Server?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-server

I working on an app in which I am using Parse as a backend. I am implementing Push notification using Parse. I have done all the configurations in the app side. 
But I am not able to find any space on Parse server to upload .p12 file or Push notification key.

I am attaching screenshot which is visible to me. 
[image]
[image]

I have checked all the possible options to upload the push certificates. But unfortunately I didn't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at the [push notifications quick start](https://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/#push-notifications-quick-start) section in the Parse Server Guide.

It states that 'when initialising Parse Server, you should pass an additional push configuration' as shown below...

```
var server = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: '...',
  cloud: '...',
  appId: '...',
  masterKey: '...',
  push: {
    android: {
      apiKey: '...'
    },
    ios: {
      pfx: '/file/path/to/XXX.p12',
      passphrase: '', // optional password to your p12/PFX
      bundleId: '',
      production: false
    }
  }
});
```

Take a look at the section in the docs mentioned above for more details on implementing push notifications with Parse Server such as additional configuration options.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I have gone through Parse Doc, but I am unable to see a place where I can write the above code. Since above code is not in Swift. So plz suggest me how can I write it.

Comment: The above code is to configure Parse Server (not a client side configuration). It may be in a file called `index.js` on your server.

Comment: Thanks for quick response